# How do I know which observations belong to which cluster?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical

I ran hierarchical clustering in R, and how can I which observation belongs to which cluster? Thanks!

```
 ### Hierarchical Clustering
 d <- dist(EMEA_2, method = "euclidean") # distance matrix
 fit <- hclust(d, method="complete") 

 ### Decide bet number of clusters 
 library(knitr)
 library(NbClust)

 nc<-NbClust(data = EMEA_2, distance = "euclidean", min.nc=2, max.nc=15, method = "complete", index = "db", alphaBeale = 0.1)

 groups <- cutree(fit, k=2) # cut tree into 2 clusters

 ### Get group means and number of frequencies within each cluster
 a2<-aggregate(EMEA_2, list(groups),mean)
 a4<-data.frame(Cluster = a2[,1], Freq = as.vector(table(groups)), a2[,-1])
```

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: @mtoto I just edited thanks!

Comment: look at `str(nc)` I suspect there will be data.frame 'clusters' as is in `stats::kmeans`. Then you can access it as `nc$clusters$ or whatever it is called there.

Comment: @JanSila Thanks! I dis try the str function, but cannot find the information that I need. Could you please explain more in detail?

Comment: @CrubalChenxiLi See my answer below. Is it what you need?

Comment: @JanSila That's cool! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in the optimisation result from `NbClust`, you will find it in `nc$Best.partition` where each number is the cluster number for respective row in the data matrix.

for example

```
> nc$Best.partition
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 3 5 1 1 4 1 4 1 5 1 5 1 4 2
```

for 20x10 data matrix.